# How to get Lottie to play from a zip file

Tags: lottie

I am trying to get Lottie to play from a zip file. Playing from a zip file is referenced in the [documentation](https://airbnb.io/lottie/android/images.html#zip-file) but I can't find an example of how to implement it. Below is my code. In the zip file is the data.json file along with the required images folder which contains all the .png used.

```
lottie.loadAnimation({
  container: document.getElementById("goHere"),
  renderer: 'svg',
  loop: true,
  autoplay: true,
  path: 'animation.zip' // the path to the animation json
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That documentation is related to the `android` player.
https://airbnb.io/lottie/#/android?id=zip-file

> Unfortunately, the web player doesn't have this feature.